# i am trying to create a http server in python using SimpleHTTPServer and getting error

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer

class HttpRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHttpRequestHandler) :

    def do_GET(self) :

            if self.path == '/admin' :
                    print "This page is only for admins"

            else :
                    SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHttpRequestHandler(self)

addr = (('0.0.0.0',10001))
httpServer = SocketServer.TCPServer(addr,HttpRequestHandler)
httpServer.serve_forever()
```

I am getting the error `'module' object has no attribute 'SimpleHttpRequestHandler'`, why is this error occurring?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` not `SimpleHttpRequestHandler`, the `HTTP` is uppercase.